# How to connect to a different MySQL port via mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, port

In PHP's [mysqli doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), it says

> mysqli mysqli_connect ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host")
>   [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd
>   = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket =
>   ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )

but when I do

```
$dblink = new \mysqli($c['host'], $c['user'], $c['pass'], $c['name'], $c['port']);
```

it connect to the default port.
Only after I did this

```
$dblink = new \mysqli($c['host'].":".$c['port'], $c['user'], $c['pass'], $c['name'], $c['port']);
```

did it connect to the right port.

Comment: You've answered your own question...

Comment: Is `$c['host'] == 'localhost'` in your case?

Comment: Yes, @axiac, but the doc says that the port can be mentioned as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) mentions:

> **host**
>
> Can be either a host name or an IP address. Passing the `NULL` value or the string `"localhost"` to this parameter, the local host is assumed. When possible, pipes will be used instead of the TCP/IP protocol.

This is the behaviour of the underlying `libmysql` library. It is also mentioned in the documentation of the deprecated [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) function where **the solution** is also provided:

> **Note:**
>
> Whenever you specify `"localhost"` or `"localhost:port"` as server, the MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local socket (named pipe on Windows). If you want to use TCP/IP, use `"127.0.0.1"` instead of `"localhost"`.

The behaviour is also specified in the documentation of [PDO_MYSQL DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) but it is more obscure this time:

> **Note: Unix only:**
>
> When the host name is set to `"localhost"`, then the connection to the server is made thru a domain socket. If `PDO_MYSQL` is compiled against `libmysqlclient` then the location of the socket file is at `libmysqlclient`'s compiled in location. If `PDO_MYSQL` is compiled against `mysqlnd` a default socket can be set thru the `pdo_mysql.default_socket setting`.

Answer (score 0):

After connect to the mysql, you can check out the info of connection.

```
$dblink = new \mysqli($c['host'], $c['user'], $c['pass'], $c['name'], $c['port']);
if ($dblink->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $dblink->connect_errno . ') '. $dblink->connect_error);
}
echo $dblink->host_info;
```

Comment: There's no error / exception thrown. It looks like its just ignoring the port argument in the mysqli constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, despite what others said.
From my tests, these are the results:

1. If you leave the localhost empty, REGARDLESS of the port, it will connect to the default port, regardless of the last parameter
2. If you put the string "localhost" as a localhost, it will still connect to the default port, regardless of the last parameter
3. Only if you set localhost to 127.0.0.1 **OR ANY OTHER IP WITH A MYSQL SERVER** then the last parameter will be accepted and used.

So, my solution is to force the localhost to "127.0.0.1" if the user selects an empty localhost, so the connect will be forced to use the port.